# Memory error when using androguard module in Yara Rules

Tags: python, yara, androguard

I tried installing [Yara](https://github.com/VirusTotal/yara) 3.8.1 with [androguard module](https://github.com/Koodous/androguard-yara). During the installation, I faced [this issue](https://github.com/Koodous/androguard-yara/issues/8), so I applied the patch given by @reox to the `androguard.c` file and it solved the problem. After that I tried a simple Yara rule with `import "androguard"` using command-line and it worked perfectly. Then I tried to use Yara rules inside my python app so I installed [yara-python](https://github.com/VirusTotal/yara-python) and used it in this way:

```
import yara

dex_path = './classes.dex'
my_rule = './rule.yar'
json_data = load_json_data()

rule = yara.compile(my_rule)
matches = rule.match(filepath=dex_path, modules_data={'androguard': json_data})
print(matches)
```

The `match` function works good when using Yara rules without `import "androguard"` module but when I want to apply a rule which imports androguard, the `match` function gives an error :

```
yara.Error: could not map file "./classes.dex" into memory
```

I'm applying a simple rule to an small file, in order of KB. I think that the problem is with the androguard module since when I remove the `import "androguard"`, it works correctly. Any idea?

Comment: Androgaurd has some memory leak issues. When a 4MB file was analysed, it is consuming ~2GB of memory.

Comment: @ChillarAnand So why it doesn't cause memory leak issue when i use it inside command line ( `yara -x androguard=andro-report.json rule.yar sample.apk`) ? I don't know exactly the origin of problem, is it Androguard iteslt, or maybe the [androguar-yara](https://github.com/Koodous/androguard-yara) module or [yara-python](https://github.com/VirusTotal/yara-python) module?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same mistake with androguard, I solve the problem installing yara-python in the version 3.8.0

https://github.com/VirusTotal/yara-python/releases/tag/v3.8.0